# XMLException was unhandled '/' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 4, position 18

Tags: c#, xml

Dynamically I am trying to create xml file thru c# code, but getting the below exception:

XMLException was unhandled '/' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 4, position 18.

Here is my code:

```
string docAuthor = document.Info.Author.ToString();
string docCreationDate = document.Info.CreationDate.ToString();

 StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
 XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
 xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
 xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
 xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
 xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("information");
 xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Author Name", docAuthor.ToString());
 xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Creation Date", docCreationDate.ToString());
 xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
 xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();
 XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
 docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
 //write the path where you want to save the Xml file
 docSave.Save(@"C:\Information.xml");
```

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XML elements cannot have spaces` in name. Remove space between `Author Name` and `Creation Date`. It should be -

```
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("AuthorName", docAuthor.ToString());
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("CreationDate", docCreationDate.ToString());
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting this an answer then it if it solves your query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Flush()` to clear the writer's internal buffer.
Until then, the backing `StringWriter` will have a half-written document.

However, you shouldn't do this at all; you should save directly to a `FileStream`.

Comment: agree, creating a XmlDocument to load the xml then save it to a file seems tedious.